# how to update table1 with records from table2 using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, updates

I have two tables:

`Table1`:

```
RulesVectorID(nullable, primary),Weight,IsDeleted
```

`Table2`:

```
RulesVectorID(forigen) , Weight,IsDeleted, NumberOfOffers, other fields...
```

I want to do tow things:

1. assign `Id` to all rows in table1 `where RulesVectorID ==null`

   I tried this:

   ```
   UPDATE myTable1
   SET RulesVectorID = SELECT MAX(RulesVectorID) + 1 FROM myTable1,
   WHERE RulesVectorID IS NULL
   ```
2. To rows added in step (1) I want to copy their `Weight, IsDeleted` columns and add 1 to their `NumberOfOffers`

   I tried this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO myTable2 (Weight, IsDeleted, NumberOfOffers, RulesVectorID) 
   VALUES (
     SELECT Weight, IsDeleted, 1, RulesVectorID 
     FROM myTable1 
     WHERE myTable1.RulesVectorID NOT IN (SELECT RulesVectorID FROM myTable2))
   ```

Is there any cleaner way to do it?

Comment: by asking if there is a cleaner way to do it, does that mean what you have works?  If it works, use it.  It's pretty reasonable.  After you get the table fixed, change RulesVectorID to auto increment, and make it a primary key so it will not be nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with t as (
select *, rn=row_number() over (order by weight)
from mytable1
where RulesVectorID is null)
update t set RulesVectorID = rn + isnull((Select max(RulesVectorID) from myTable1),0);
```

Second query looks ok once you drop the `values()`

```
insert into myTable2 (Weight,IsDeleted,NumberOfOffers,RulesVectorID) 
select Weight,IsDeleted,1,RulesVectorID 
from myTable1 
where myTable1.RulesVectorID not in (select RulesVectorID from myTable2)
```

Comment: why is it needed to `(order by weight)` ?

Comment: why is it OK with `values()`?

Answer (score 1):

Given you have an index on [uniqueID] column in each table and you just want to update existing rows in Table 1 with data in Table 2 and that [uniqueID] is supposed to be the same between the two tables you can try the following:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.stfips=Table2.NEWstfips,
    Table1.areatype=Table2.NEWareatype,
    Table1.area=Table2.NEWarea
FROM Table2
JOIN Table1
    ON Table1.uniqueid=Table2.uniqueid
```

We use this in our staging databases so speed is not that great of a concern. Back of the envelop testing of 13 million records shows this takes about 15 seconds on our hardware (YMMV).